# $\Phi:M\to M$ be a smooth map whose restriction to $\partial M$ is the identity

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

> Let $M$ be a connected oriented smooth n-dimensional
>   manifold-with-boundary, and let $\Phi:M\to M$ be a smooth map whose
>   restriction to $\partial M$ is the identity. If $\omega$ is any smooth
>   n-form on $M$, prove that $\deg \Phi=1$, i.e. $$ \int_M \Phi^* \omega = \int _M \omega $$

My attempt is to consider the homological sequence of the pair $(M, \partial M)$, and try to show $\Phi^*: H^n(M)\to H^n(M)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Excuse me. Would you mind providing some hints?

Comment: @MikeMiller Are you referring to the "classical" Stokes' Theorem or the general version?

Comment: @cpiegore: The general version, of course.

Comment: Stoke's theorem can only apply to $d\omega$ over $M$ for some n-1 form, how does this work?

Comment: @Henry: What do you know about $H^n(M)$ when $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary?

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean $H_n(M)$ coincides with $H_c^n(M)$. I am sorry I am not familiar with some properties of this $M$. Would you mind providing more detail or a reference?

Comment: By Lefschetz duality, $H^n(M) \cong H_0(M,\partial M) = 0$ when $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary. So does this help? (You can find Lefschetz duality in Hatcher or any other reasonable algebraic topology book.)

Comment: @TedShifrin $M$ is oriented, so immediately we have $H^n(M)\cong \mathbb R$ for the nonvanishing n-form?

Comment: No, $H^n(M)=0$ because $M$ has boundary. Try $M$ to be $D^n = \{x\in\Bbb R^n: \|x\|\le 1\}$.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot~